# How do I call a method asynchronously, but on a specific thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

From Thread A I wish to call `MethodA()` asynchronously (such that it doesn't block Thread A) to be run on Thread B a specific thread that I have started, such that it interrupts what Thread B is doing.

Is this possible without having to actively poll for `MethodA()` call requests in Thread B?

**EDIT:** more specifically, I wish for all calls to `MethodA()` to be on Thread B.

**EDIT 2:** neither thread is a UI thread. Although I know Thread B is running, it would be nice to be able to return false if its not/not throw an exception.

Comment: If you want it to run on that thread, then just run it synchronously on that thread. MethodA() could just trigger an AutoResetEvent that Thread B checks for.

Comment: Are both threads running? do you have access to Thread2?

Comment: You can probably use SynchronizationContext

Comment: If Thread B is UI thread you can call MethodA by SyncronizationContext of UI Thread.

Comment: See edits to the OP guys. Thanks.

Comment: _"such that it interrupts what Thread B is doing"_ - why, in heavens name?  This isn't possible, and that's a good thing.

Comment: What about SynchronizationContext, or does that only execute the messages when the thread has finished its work? Surely this must be possible as it happens with the UI all the time?

Comment: Nope - UI threads are typically constructed as loops around an input queue.  Mouse/keyboard etc. events and SynchronizationContexts are queued to the UI thread and executed serially as they are popped.  If a thread is interrupted and something else is run, that is going to be a driver and often another thread, not the interrupted thread.

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to do without creating a specific implementation of Thread B worker.
Thread B worker should be something like infinite-loop or another signaling mechanism like `EventWaitHandle`. On each iteration of loop Thread B worker should check some queue of delegates which can be populated by another thread.